# Equal 1st and 2nd degree sums implies equal entries

Tags: summation, arithmetic, variance

Let's say we have 2 sets of entries $x_i$ and $y_i$ for $i=1(1)n$. We are given two facts are told that they're true. Which are:

1. $\Sigma x_i = \Sigma y_i$, i.e. their **linear/first order sums** are equal.
2. $\Sigma {x_i}^{2} = \Sigma {y_i}^{2}$, i.e. their **second order sums** are equal.

Can we therefore conclude that **$x_i=y_i$** for each $i$?

*Actually, this is a bit imprecise. A better way to present my question would be to ask: **Can we therefore say,** $$\Bigl( X= \{ x_i\mid i=1(1)n \} \Bigr) = \Bigl( Y= \{ y_i\mid i=1(1)n \} \Bigr) ?$$*

So my question is this: **If 2 sets of entries have the same 1st and 2nd order sums, should the 2 sets be equal?**

***Extended Discussion:***

1. If we take some other pair of consecutive orders, such as **3rd and 4th**, and say that the *sums of the 2 sets of entries in each those respective orders are equal*, then should our entry **sets** be, again, **equal**?
2. What if we take **non consecutive orders? Such as 10th and 15th?**
3. What if we take fractional orders?

P.S.: I might've tagged irrelevant topics for this question. I'm not sure what this question falls under. Any help will be acknowledged.

Comment: It is not true. Try some simple examples.

Comment: Keep trying. It can be done with $n$ as small as three.

Comment: It can be done with $n=3$ just using whole numbers, taken from the set $\{\,0,1,2,3,4\,\}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Or $n=3$ and numbers from the set $\{1,2,4,5\}$ if you want positive integers, or from the set $\{1,2,3,5,6,7\}$ for distinct positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your first multiset of numbers $\{x,y,z\}$. Then without loss of generality the second multiset will be $\{x+\delta_1,y+\delta_2,z-\delta_1-\delta_2\}$.

Simplify the equation which equates their sums of squares.

You will get a linear equation in $x,y,z$.

Pick any two values for $\delta_1,\delta_2$.

You then just need to solve a single linear equation in $3$ variables.

Just make sure you are not unlucky enough to pick values so that you end up with the same set as you started with, in a different order.  You have so much freedom that you can avoid this easily.